# Command line to find bluetooth device's MAC address

Tags: macos, command-line, bluetooth, unix

Is there a way to get the MAC address of the Bluetooth device in my Mac? I am using a MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra. I am looking mainly for macOS but the command could also be for another UNIX or Linux machine.

It should be the same as the one shown when <kbd>Option</kbd> clicking the Bluetooth icon in the status menus in the Menu Bar.

[image: bluetooth icon]

Comment: Note that Linux and MacOS are quite different at this level.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Execute the following command line in macOS:

`system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType`

The output will print details about the build-in Bluetooth device along with the MAC address. The output will also list the paired devices along with their MAC addresses.

Comment: Awesome! Works on my OSX machine. Is this linux and debian-friendly as well?

Comment: This is a macOS specific command.