# How to find the Bluetooth MAC address of a paired device?

Tags: macos, ios, network, command-line, bluetooth

Either iOS or MacOS solution please that works currently with the latest software — haven’t found any working solution online, but I know there must be a way.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336264/command-line-to-find-bluetooth-devices-mac-address with both option-click in menubar and command line. Still works with macOS 13.5